# Magento2 : Best way to handle Multi Device login using REST API Auth

Tags: magento2.2.2, customer-session, rest-api, oauth, mobile-login

I am creating an auth token for mobile customer using

```
  /V1/integration/customer/token
```

When I use the same customer credentials in Second mobile device the first auth token is invalidated as the when requesting again it overwrites token for that customer

What the best way to get around it , i started with introducing as deviceId column that table and overwriting only in case when customer id and device Id matches . Is there any better approach